# Obtaining Time zone in android

Tags: android, datetime, timezone

Is there a way to obtain the time zone from the callbacks received

```
void onLocationChanged(Location location)
```

using the time information that can be obtained from the location parameter

```
long Time = location.getTime();
```

Or if there is another way please provide info!

Comment: You should elaborate your problem, because obviously there are no clear solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use web service provided by the geonames.org.
Supply latitude and longitude to get the time zone information.

http://ws.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=47.01&lng=10.2:

```
{"time":"2010-07-24 18:35","countryName":"Austria","sunset":"2010-07-24 21:02","rawOffset":1,"dstOffset":2,"countryCode":"AT","gmtOffset":1,"lng":10.2,"sunrise":"2010-07-24 05:48","timezoneId":"Europe/Vienna","lat":47.01}
```

Comment: That might work, but I want something that does not depend on an internet connection. Perhaps implementing  the same algorithm for my application.

Comment: That is possible, but you will need to distribute the database of countries, locations and time zones with your application. Also note that daylight saving information may change within 2 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use java.util.TimeZone to get information about the current time zone by calling TimeZone.getDefault(), like:

```
java.util.TimeZone tz = java.util.TimeZone.getDefault();
Toast.makeText(context, tz.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Correct but this returns the phone's time zone which might be incorrect , or inaccurate due to the fact that the user is traveling

Comment: Alright, I misunderstood your intention then. Since the location times are always UTC I don't think there is a mechanism in place to support this. That would require some sort of geocode to time zone mapping, which exists in some GPS devices. Maybe a future feature for Android...

Comment: I think Android will automatically suggest to change the default timezone when roaming to another country.

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println("TimeZone   "+tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)+"   Timezon id :: " + tz.getID());
```

OutPut

```
TimeZone   GMT+09:30   Timezon id :: Australia/Darwin
```